# Pointer in Vector

Tags: c++, pointers, vector

```
std::vector<int*> * vec=new std::vector<int*>();
int* p=new int();
int* q=new int();
vec.push_back(p);
vec.push_back(q);
.
.
.
vec.clear();
```

My Question is will the memory is deallocated ???

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but `vector::push_back` takes an argument of type `T` and not `void`?

Comment: @H2CO3 Yes that is correct, but it is not particularly relevant to the question.

Answer (score 3):

The memory holding the pointers, yes. The memory holding pointer's contents, no. Also, you should free the vector itself by writing `delete vec;` at the end of the program, but I guess, that it's not what you are asking for.

Answer (score 2):

No. You should use `delete`, when you use `new` (and not use smart-pointers).
And for elements of vector - no, the memory will not be deallocated, you should use `delete` on each element in vector. Something like

```
std::for_each(vec.begin(), vec.end(), [](const int* p) { delete p; });
```